No IAM role showing up when scheduling query in redshift serverless from root user
I am trying to schedule a query in redshift serverless using query scheduler v2.
I have created a role copy-s3-to-redshift, with permissions as

AmazonEventBridgeFullAccess
AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess
AmazonRedshiftFullAccess
AmazonRedshiftQueryEditorV2FullAccess

I am doing this all under root user.I am unable to see the IAM role i have defined when scheduling query.
I have referred to this link so far but it explains how it should done for a user, and not root user.

Did you forget to attach it to your redshift instance?
This IAM role is also attached to your cluster or workgroup.

